# Exported JAR file does not show images

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a Java project in Eclipse. This is the folder structure:

[image: Eclipse folder structure]

The code packages are located in src, and all images are in the res folder.

Images in the code are referenced like this:

```
new ImageIcon("res/settings.gif");
```

However, after I export the project to a JAR file (by using Export -> Runnable JAR File in Eclipse), and run the JAR, no images are shown. If I open the JAR with WinRAR, this is its structure:

[image: JAR structure]

All images are in the root folder, and can't be references correctly. How do I properly reference the images so that they are visible both from Eclipse and from the exported JAR?

Comment: What options are you selecting when exporting the Jar?

Comment: I think because there is a difference in what eclipse runs as its main folder and what the jar considers its main folder. In either case maybe use the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the fix:

Replace this

```
new ImageIcon("res/settings.gif");
```

with

```
new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/settings.gif"));
```

Works both from Eclipse and from a runnable JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

The `res/` folder is not created in the .jar file. It looks that the resource location should not be `"res/settings.gif"` but `"/settings.gif"`.

You are getting it to work if you debug in Eclipse because the home directory would be the root of your project, where the `res/` folder actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be either to use an absolute path

```
new ImageIcon("/settings.gif");
```

or ensure that the `res` folder is copied into the jar. Maybe src/res or mark the folder as source folder in eclipse; I now am in another IDE.

Then it would be

```
new ImageIcon("/res/settings.gif");
```

Comment: Are you sure that ImageIcon can load images from resources? The used constructor with one String argument is AFAIK for specifying a file name, not a resource name.